# Use ObjectListView For A Logbook With An XML File

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I'm creating a logbook application that allows you to create data fields for logbook entries and uses an ObjectListView to display the data. However, this presents a problem. Since field names can change from logbook to logbook, I can't write a single class to deal with the presentation of logbooks.

The application will use an XML format like this:

```
<entry date="2/18/2014">
  <field name="hours" type="int" value="3" display="Hours Used"/>
  <field name="gallons" type="double" value="6.8" display="Gallons Used"/>
  <filed name="comment" type="string" value="..." display="Comment"/>
</entry>
```

How can I turn an XML file like the above into data that an ObjectListView can display?

Comment: I don't know what an `ObjectListView` is, but you should be using WPF instead, which has built-in support for DataBinding to XML.

Comment: It's basically a ListView on steroids: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Comment: my point still stands.